# xml deserialization - I am getting 0 item with some node that has attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have an stripped down XML sample here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node1>
    <items>
        <item>
            <displayname>planet_one</displayname>
            <atmosphere>
                <part type="value">
                    <![CDATA[Hydrogen]]>
                </part>
            </atmosphere>
        </item>
        <item>
            <displayname>planet_two</displayname>
            <atmosphere>
                <part type="value">
                    <![CDATA[Hydrogen]]>
                </part>
                <part type="value">
                    <![CDATA[Sulfur]]>
                </part>
                <part type="value">
                    <![CDATA[Acid]]>
                </part>
            </atmosphere>
        </item>
    </items>
</node1>
```

I am not sure after diserialization, I keep getting zero atmosphere? I am not sure why, I tried changing my code for it but I still keep getting zero. here's the test code for you to test out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><node1><items><item><displayname>planet_one</displayname><atmosphere><part type=\"value\"><![CDATA[Hydrogen]]></part></atmosphere></item><item><displayname>planet_two</displayname><atmosphere><part type=\"value\"><![CDATA[Hydrogen]]></part><part type=\"value\"><![CDATA[Sulfur]]></part><part type=\"value\"><![CDATA[Acid]]></part></atmosphere></item></items></node1>";

            var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(node1));
            var streamXML = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
            var output = serialiser.Deserialize(streamXML);

            node1 iData = (node1)output;

            foreach (item n in iData.items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.displayname);
                Console.WriteLine("atmospheres count: " + n.atmosphere.Count);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class node1
    {
        List<item> _items = new List<item>();
        public List<item> items
        {
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }
            set
            {
                _items = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class atmosphere
    {
        public string part { get; set; }
    }

    public class item
    {
        public string displayname { get; set; }

        List<atmosphere> _atmosphere = new List<atmosphere>();
        public List<atmosphere> atmosphere
        {
            get
            {
                return _atmosphere;
            }
            set
            {
                _atmosphere = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output here is

```
planet_one
atmospheres count: 0
planet_two
atmospheres count: 0
done
```

again, the question is why zero? did I missed something?

**-- update SOLVED --**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><node1><items><item><displayname>planet_one</displayname><atmosphere><part type=\"value\"><![CDATA[Hydrogen]]></part></atmosphere></item><item><displayname>planet_two</displayname><atmosphere><part type=\"value\"><![CDATA[Hydrogen]]></part><part type=\"value\"><![CDATA[Sulfur]]></part><part type=\"value\"><![CDATA[Acid]]></part></atmosphere></item></items></node1>";

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("d:\\test.xml"))
            {
                xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(node1));
            var streamXML = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
            var output = serialiser.Deserialize(streamXML);

            node1 iData = (node1)output;

            foreach (item n in iData.items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.displayname);
                Console.WriteLine("atmospheres count: " + n.atmosphere.parts.Length);
                foreach (string a in n.atmosphere.parts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("    " + a);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("-------------\r\n");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class node1
    {
        public item[] items { get; set; }
    }

    public class atmosphere
    {
        [XmlElement("part")]
        public string[] parts { get; set; }
    }

    public class item
    {
        public string displayname { get; set; }

        public atmosphere atmosphere { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That´s because the property `atmosphere` in your `item` class should be a list of a class named `part` instead of `atmosphere`. That class should contain the type attribute and the inner data:

```
public class item
{
    public string displayname { get; set; }

    List<part> _atmosphere = new List<part>();
    public List<part> atmosphere
    {
        get
        {
            return _atmosphere;
        }
        set
        {
            _atmosphere = value;
        }
    }
}

public class part
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }

    string _data;
    [XmlText]
    public string Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set { _data = value; }
    }
}
```

If you want the class holding the  elements to continue being named `atmosphere`, you can do that using the attribute `[XmlArrayItem("part")]` on the atmosphere property (which now will be of type `List<atmosphere>`) so the serializer knows the name of the element in the xml is "part" instead of "atmosphere" (Because by default it will expect the name of the element to be the same as the name of the class):

```
public class item
{
    public string displayname { get; set; }

    List<atmosphere> _atmosphere = new List<atmosphere>();
    [XmlArrayItem("part")]
    public List<atmosphere> atmosphere
    {
        get
        {
            return _atmosphere;
        }
        set
        {
            _atmosphere = value;
        }
    }
}

public class atmosphere
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }

    string _data;
    [XmlText]
    public string Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set { _data = value; }
    }
}
```

Both approaches will give you the expected results when using your test code.

Comment: I have solved the problem right before your post your solution. but as a gift to your effort, I will mark you solution as an answer.